# In the Visual Studio debugger, what does {null=???} mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, boost

I was debugging a C++ program in VS 2003, and a boost variable showed up as having the value {null=???}. What does that mean?

Comment: What was the type of the variable? The three question marks generally mean "memory read error".

Comment: The type of the variable was a boost pointer to a guid type. Good to know that ??? means memory read error, thanks. But what would the "null=" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically when you see ??? in the C++ debugger, it means the underlying expression evaluator had problems accessing the memory for the particular expression.  So it's likely the value points to invalid or inaccessible memory.

It's also possible that this session is using an [autoexp.dat](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/V-S/debug/article.php/c1281) file and it points to a member that is not accessible / available in the underlying expression.  I believe this will also lead to the ??? display.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hadn't considered. I will check it out next time I can.